# Help with finding the length of one of the sides of a triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

\begin{align}\frac z{\sin E}&=\frac y{\sin D}\tag{1}\\
z^2 &= x^2 + y^2 - 2xy\cos E\tag{2}\\
y^2 &= z^2 + x^2 - 2zx\cos D\tag{3}\end{align}

Solve for $z$

My solution is as follow.
[image]

I stopped at the equation:

$$(2xy)^2 - (x^2 + y^2 - z^2)^2 = (2zx)^2 - (z^2 + x^2 - y^2)^2$$

Please help me solve for $z$ in the above equation.

Thank you

Comment: I think, It's impossible. We need more given.

Comment: All data are given.  Also, I arrived at the equation:                                                    (2xy)^2 - (x^2 + y^2 - z^2)^2 = (2zx)^2 - (z^2 + x^2 - y^2)^2                                     There is only one unknown in the above equation, which is z.                                 x and y are given, and they are x = 70.64622683 and y = 147.2977643

Comment: are the angles given?

Comment: Angles are not given

Comment: The reason why I stopped at the equation:                                          
  (2xy)^2 - (x^2 + y^2 - z^2)^2 = (2zx)^2 - (z^2 + x^2 - y^2)^2                             is because I don't know how to solve a quartic function.

Comment: You probably need at least one angle. As it is there in the picture we can change the angle $E$ at will between $0$ and $180$ and obtain any specified length for $z$ that we like by choosing appropriate angles then for $E$ and $F$.

Comment: Yes, I understand that there is more than one solution for E, but among these many solutions, can you just give me one solution that satisfy the given x and y.  In other words, just show me how to solve the quartic function: (2xy)^2 - (x^2 + y^2 - z^2)^2 = (2zx)^2 - (z^2 + x^2 - y^2)^2.  I can tell you the answer:  z = 172
F = 24
D = 58
E = 98
    However, can you show me the steps in solving the quartic function to arrive at z = 172.

Comment: based on the triangle inequality, you can estimate y-x<z<x+y, however, to find z uniquely, the triangle must be uniquely defined...

Answer (score 0):

If you expand your final equation $$(2xy)^2 - (x^2 + y^2 - z^2)^2 = (2zx)^2 - (z^2 + x^2 - y^2)^2$$ you will get an equation which has equal terms in $x^4$, $y^4$, and $z^4$ on both sides. Removing these gets you:

$$2x^2y^2 + 2x^2z^2 + 2y^2z^2 = 2x^2y^2 + 2x^2z^2 + 2y^2z^2$$

which as you can see is always true.

The problem is that all your algebraic manipulations cannot *add information*, they can just rearrange what you already know. Look at your diagram. You have two sides of a triangle, and nothing else. There are an **infinite** number of triangles you can make that have two sides of given lengths. You can see this physically - get two sticks, attach their ends, and pivot. Every position gives you a new triangle, with a different third side length.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent explanation.  You are a good teacher.